# intent.PutExtra requires Android.OS.Bundle

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I am trying to pass an object to another class and I see that everyone uses:

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
intent.PutExtra("0", player); 
this.StartActivity(intent);
```

my object is "player"

```
player = MediaPlayer.Create(Application.Context, RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Ringtone));
```

I thought I could pass the player object with the intent but it says "cannot convert from 'Android.Media.MediaPlayer' to 'Android.OS.Bundle'"

Is there something I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option is to have a public accessible player that can be called when you need it

Here is a small example

In Your Main Activity Create the following global var

```
    public static Android.Media.MediaPlayer player { get; set; }
```

then you can call it anywhere you want via

```
   MainActivity.player
```